# PubNub EON Graph

Tags: iot, pubnub

My sensor data consists of temperature and humidity. I can already console those datas temp and humid, to a single graph using simple example provided by pubnub. Now I decide to separate the temp and humid into 2 different graph, the temperature graph on top and humidity graph on bottom so that it can be viewed better and clearer due to resolution. How can I implement this using the eon sdk?
The formatted json data sent is,

```
"eon":{"tpr":%.1f,"hum":%.1f}
```

Here's the code i'm following,

```js
<body>
    <h1>Getting Started with EON</h1>
    <p>Create real-time charts and maps.</p>
    <div id="chart12"></div>
    <div id="chart13"></div>
    <script>
          var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
            publish_key:   'pub-c-3d6b4414-redacted', // replace with your own pub-key
            subscribe_key: 'sub-c-0d045036-redacted' // replace with your own sub-key
          });

          eon.chart({
            pubnub: pubnub,         
            channel: "birdpeek", // the pubnub channel for real time data
            limit:20,
            flow:true,
            generate: {           // c3 chart object
              bindto: '#chart12',
              data: {
                type: 'spline',
                labels: true
              }
            }
          });
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to create two different eon charts in one page, maybe one in each div. You can probably create a [line chart](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart/blob/master/examples/simple.html) for the temperature, and a [gauge chart](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart/blob/master/examples/gauge.html) for the humidity. You are just pulling out the same data in different places(charts)

Comment: How to bind to chart13 as it'd been done in chart12? Chart12 does not separate the tem and hum but it consoles both output in single graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub EON Chart - Two Charts, Same Page

Publishing this data: `{"eon":{"tpr":"%.1f","hum":"%.1f"}}`

### Two Channels

If publishing to two different channels, you can do it like this:

```js
<div id="chart-temp"></div>
<div id="chart-humid"></div>
<script>
  var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey:   'your-pub-key', 
    subscribeKey: 'your-sub-key'
  });
  var charTemp = eon.chart({
    pubnub: pubnub,
    channels: ["temperature"],
    generate: {
      bindto: '#chart-temp',
      data: {
        labels: true
      }
    }
  });
  var chartHumid = eon.chart({
    pubnub: pubnub,
    channels: ["humidity"],
    generate: {
      bindto: '#chart-humid',
      data: {
        labels: true
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

### One Channel

If you must publish to a single channel then each `eon.chart` will have to use the same channel and mutate the received data to only include the necessary data for that chart.

```js
<div id="chart-temp"></div>
<div id="chart-humid"></div>
<script>
  var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey:   'your-pub-key', 
    subscribeKey: 'your-sub-key'
  });
  var charTemp = eon.chart({
    pubnub: pubnub,
    channels: ["birdpeek"],
    generate: {
      bindto: '#chart-temp',
      data: {
        labels: true
      }
    }
    transform : function(data) {
        return {eon:{'Humidity': data.eon.hum}  }
    }
  });
  var chartHumid = eon.chart({
    pubnub: pubnub,
    channels: ["birdpeek"],
    generate: {
      bindto: '#chart-humid',
      data: {
        labels: true
      }
    }
    transform : function(data) {
        return {eon:{'Humidity': data.eon.tpr}}
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: From your code it retrieves the data sources (tpr n humid) from 2 different channels namely ["temperature"] and ["humidity"] but my iot device publishing the datas on a single same channel namely "birdpeek". My problem how to extract the data --> "eon":{"tpr":%.1f,"hum":%.1f} then output to 2 different id of <div>

Comment: Use the same channel for both charts and mutate the result using the `transform` callback function of the `eon.chart` object. I will update my answer with proper `transform` code.

Comment: Your transform code appears nothing in the console but i managed to grab the format idea from the sdk example transform. The correct code below.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
          var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
            publish_key:   'pub-c-3d6b4414-xxx', // replace with your own pub-key
            subscribe_key: 'sub-c-0d045036-xxx' // replace with your own sub-key
          });

          eon.chart({
            pubnub: pubnub,         
            channel: "birdpeek", // the pubnub channel for real time data
            limit:20,
            flow:true,
            generate: {           // c3 chart object
              bindto: '#chart12',
              data: {
                type: 'spline',
                x: 'x',
                labels: true
              },
              axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%H:%m:%S'
                    }
                }
              }
            },
            transform : function(data) {

                return {eon:{'Humidity': data.eon.hum}  }


            }
          });

          eon.chart({
            pubnub: pubnub,         
            channel: "birdpeek", // the pubnub channel for real time data
            limit:20,
            flow:true,
            generate: {           // c3 chart object
              bindto: '#chart13',
              data: {
                type: 'spline',
                x: 'x',
                labels: true
              },
              axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%H:%m:%S'
                    }
                }
              }
            },
            transform : function(data) {

                return {eon:{'Temperature': data.eon.tpr}   }


            }
          });


    </script>
```

Comment: nice - I changed my code to match yours - but upvoting you, too.